# Export SMS & MMS messages from Samsung S23

Tags: sms, mms

I want to get a readable backup of my messages. I want something that works like, e.g., [Coolmuster](https://www.coolmuster.com/android-assistant-apk.html) but ideally for any OS (Ubuntu) and fast, doing only one thing, ideally copying all SMS and MMS as if it's a file system that I can read messages portable after transferring them. Samsung Switch created some unreadable SMEM files, where I could read the media files but not the text from the messages. So if there isn't one, I will buy the Coolmuster app.[image] since it appears to connect and work, but I would prefer something like a "raw" readable data format, e.g., like Eml for email messages.

Comment: [This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) creates an `xml` backup that can be read on computer (see app description) //No idea about Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks. I found this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jerryzigo.smsbackup&hl=en_US as well